# Returning XML From Multiple Elements in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have the following XML stored in an MS SQL table.

```
<CustomerStrategy>
  <ChampionChallenger  GroupId="BureauPhoneTest" IsChampion="1" StrategyName="New Bureau Phone Champion" IsSelected="true" />
  <ChampionChallenger GroupId="BureauPhoneTest" IsChampion="0"  StrategyName="New Bureau Phone Challenger" IsSelected=""/>
</CustomerStrategy>
```

I'm looking for those that are `IsChampion = "0"` and `IsSelected="true"` and `GroupID="BureauPhoneTest"`. There could be other champion challenger elements in the `CustomerStrategy` element.

How do I structure my SQL to only return `IsChampion = "0"` and `IsSelected="true"` and `GroupID="BureauPhoneTest"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly work with XML like:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE (
    id int,
    xmlField xml
)

INSERT INTO @x VALUES
(1, '<CustomerStrategy>
  <ChampionChallenger  GroupId="BureauPhoneTest" IsChampion="1" StrategyName="New Bureau Phone Champion" IsSelected="true" />
  <ChampionChallenger GroupId="BureauPhoneTest" IsChampion="0"  StrategyName="New Bureau Phone Challenger" IsSelected=""/>
</CustomerStrategy>'),
(2, '<CustomerStrategy>
  <ChampionChallenger  GroupId="BureauPhoneTest" IsChampion="1" StrategyName="New Bureau Phone Champion" IsSelected="true" />
  <ChampionChallenger GroupId="BureauPhoneTest" IsChampion="0"  StrategyName="New Bureau Phone Challenger" IsSelected="true"/>
</CustomerStrategy>')


SELECT DISTINCT x.id
FROM @x x
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT xmlField
    FROM xmlField.nodes('/CustomerStrategy/ChampionChallenger') as t(c)
    WHERE t.c.value('@IsChampion','bit') = 0 
            and t.c.value('@IsSelected','nvarchar(6)') = 'true'
            and t.c.value('@GroupId','nvarchar(50)') ='BureauPhoneTest'         
    ) as t
```

This will return `2`. I add one string with all conditions required.

Comment: Is, essentially, we are taking the XML and turning it into a type of temp table. Am I correct?

Comment: I meant "So", not "Is".

Answer (score 1):

It is better to inlcude the filter within `.nodes()` as `XQuery` expression.

Especially with big XML it is an overkill first to read everything, just to filter it out at the end.

The following will return `NULL` for id=1, one XML for id=2 and two entries for id=3:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id int,xmlField xml);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
(1, '<CustomerStrategy>
  <ChampionChallenger  GroupId="BureauPhoneTest" IsChampion="1" StrategyName="New Bureau Phone Champion" IsSelected="true" />
  <ChampionChallenger GroupId="BureauPhoneTest" IsChampion="0"  StrategyName="New Bureau Phone Challenger" IsSelected=""/>
</CustomerStrategy>'),
(2, '<CustomerStrategy>
  <ChampionChallenger  GroupId="BureauPhoneTest" IsChampion="1" StrategyName="New Bureau Phone Champion" IsSelected="true" />
  <ChampionChallenger GroupId="BureauPhoneTest" IsChampion="0"  StrategyName="New Bureau Phone Challenger" IsSelected="true"/>
</CustomerStrategy>'),
(3, '<CustomerStrategy>
  <ChampionChallenger  GroupId="BureauPhoneTest" IsChampion="0" StrategyName="New Bureau Phone Champion" IsSelected="true" />
  <ChampionChallenger GroupId="BureauPhoneTest" IsChampion="0"  StrategyName="New Bureau Phone Challenger" IsSelected="true"/>
</CustomerStrategy>');

SELECT t.id
      ,Filtered.query('.') AS FilteredNodes
FROM @tbl AS t
OUTER APPLY xmlField.nodes(N'/CustomerStrategy/ChampionChallenger[@IsChampion eq "0" and @IsSelected eq "true" and @GroupId eq "BureauPhoneTest"]') AS A(Filtered)
```